# How to replace a fragment by tag?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace a fragment whose id i dont have because I created it in code. But i do have its tag. Can I replace it with another fragment. Heres my code:

```
GridFragment gridFragment=new GridFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("obj",json);
                bundle.putString("from","fav");
                gridFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                android.app.FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft=man.beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(man.findFragmentByTag("tagg"),gridFragment);
```

Last statement of replace is not working as replace method needs int as first argument.

Comment: "whose id i dont have because I created it in code" -- please show the code where you added the fragment that you now want to replace.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {  super.onPostExecute(aVoid);  GridFragment gridFragment=new GridFragment();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("obj",json);
            bundle.putString("from","main");
            gridFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            android.app.FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=man.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.gridFrame,gridFragment,"tagg");
           ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
  GridFragment gridFragment=new GridFragment();
          Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("obj",json);
            bundle.putString("from","main");
            gridFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            android.app.FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=man.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.gridFrame,gridFragment,"tagg");
           ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

            p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }